# Required: widget.textView, Found: view.View - Mistake in the official GettingStarted examples?

Tags: view, textview, widget

I just got into Android Studio and followed the examples from the Android Getting Started lessons.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

On this page, there is this line, that just didn't work for me.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Writing this, Android Studio tells me:

"Incompatible Types

Required: android.widget.TextView

Found: android.view.View"

Now, I can't imagine that there's a mistake on the official page, but it only works for me, if I write.

```
TextView newView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNew);
```

Also, I checked multiple times, that the textViewNew is a TextView widget, but it is.

So, what is going on and where is the mistake?
Thanks